# SQL Server : IF ELSE condition not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE varchar(50) 
declare @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE varchar(50)
declare @CURRENT_YEAR varchar(50)

set @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE = 'jan' 
set @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE = 'jan'
set @CURRENT_YEAR = '2017'      

if ('+ @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE +' = '+ @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE +')
    if object_id (''cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +''', ''U'') is not null drop table cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +';
    (select *
    into cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'
    from '+ @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE +''+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'_final )
else 
    if object_id (''cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'_final'', ''U'') is not null drop table cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'_final;
    (select * 
    into cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'_final
    from (select *
            from cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'
            union all
            select *
            from '+ @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE +''+ @CURRENT_YEAR +'_final) as cumulative_rev)`enter code here`
```

I have the code above which throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have syntax errors everywhere in here. It looks like a disastrous hybrid of standard t-sql and dynamic sql.

Comment: I honestly don't even know where to begin... or what this is even trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you realise you have enclosed variables in single quotes ex:'+ @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE +'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing BEGIN/END blocks.

And you need to use dynamic SQL for some of that.

I'm not going to totally fix your code, but here's something that's probably closer to what you're trying to do:

```
declare @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE nvarchar(50) 
declare @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE nvarchar(50)
declare @CURRENT_YEAR nvarchar(50)

set @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE = 'jan' 
set @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE = 'jan'
set @CURRENT_YEAR = '2017'     

DECLARE @tableName sysname;
DECLARE @sourceTable sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @tableName =  N'cumulative_revenue' + @CURRENT_YEAR; 
SELECT @sourceTable = @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE + @CURRENT_YEAR + N'_final';

if (@FIRST_MONTH_TABLE = @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE)
begin
    if object_id (@tableName) is not null 
    begin 
        SELECT @sql = N'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName);
        EXEC (@sql);
        SELECT @sql = N'select * into ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' from ' + QUOTENAME(@sourceTable);
        EXEC (@sql);
   end
end
else 
begin
... etc
end
```

This should give you a template to figure out what you're doing wrong and how to do it right. It's really not clear to me EXACTLY what you're trying to do, so you're going to need to just adjust your own code yourself, based on this example.

Comment: Got it, adjusted the code to cater to what I wanna do and it works perfectly! Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have no idea if this is correct, as the SQL is a mess, however, I think this might be what you're after:

```
DECLARE @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE varchar(50) 
DECLARE @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE varchar(50)
DECLARE @CURRENT_YEAR varchar(50)

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @FIRST_MONTH_TABLE = 'jan' 
SET @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE = 'jan'
SET @CURRENT_YEAR = '2017'      


IF (@FIRST_MONTH_TABLE = @CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE) BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR, 'U') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @SQL = N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME('cumulative_revenue' + @CURRENT_YEAR) + N';';
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
        SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
                   N'INTO ' + QUOTENAME('cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR) + NCHAR(10) + 
                   N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE + @CURRENT_YEAR +N'_final') + N';';
        PRINT @SQL;
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Commented out as I can't run it
    END
END ELSE BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('cumulative_revenue' + @CURRENT_YEAR + '_final', 'U') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @SQL = N'drop table ' + QUOTENAME('cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +N'_final') + N';';
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
        SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) + 
                   N'INTO ' + QUOTENAME('cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR +N'_final') + NCHAR(10) + 
                   N'FROM (SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME('cumulative_revenue'+ @CURRENT_YEAR) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'from '+ QUOTENAME(@CURRENT_MONTH_TABLE + @CURRENT_YEAR + N'_final') + N') as cumulative_rev);'
        PRINT @SQL;
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Commented out as I can't run it
    END
END
```